# Centering an image with css not working

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I just started taking a web design class about 4 weeks ago and I'm extremely interested in it. If anyone can help a newbie like me, I'd be very grateful.

I'm not quite sure on what the problem is here. The code worked on a separate file of mine, but when
I tried to start a new project it just wouldn't work anymore. :/

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Good Boy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="goodboyslove.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/GBFavicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.oriko-san.tumblr.com/"><img id="gblogo" class="center" src="images/GB.png" alt="good boy logo" width="128" height="128">
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE css>

.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; }

#gblogo{position:relative;top:32px;}
```

Comment: What @Brian said, besides it's not a good decision to center an image which is wrapped by an anchor tag, this way. The entire space would be clickable. Try wrapping the anchor by a block level element and add `text-align: center;` to it. **[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/nuceqi/1/edit)**

Comment: I should probably specify the other project with the code working had additional coding, but I looked through it all thoroughly and couldn't find anything that would make a difference (at least to my knowledge). I'm 100% positive it is not a software error.

Comment: JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dassfkv9/1/)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe something so simple was causing the problem. Thank you so much @Brian and that was indeed the issue. ((:

Comment: Its always the little things :) Here is a good read regarding html and also has a section on the use of doctype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction

Comment: @HashemQolami that was another issue I couldn't figure out either. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doctype` is a document type declaration which is not valid in a CSS document. Removing that will solve the issue. CSS falls under a MIME type which you are declaring with the  `type="text/css"` of your link tag.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction) is a introduction article regarding HTML and includes a section of the use of `doctype`

Answer (score 0):

Try This! (**I do not guarantee**)

Your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Good Boy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="goodboyslove.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/GBFavicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.oriko-san.tumblr.com/"><img id="gblogo" class="center" src="images/GB.png" alt="good boy logo" width="128" height="128" /></a>
</body>
```

Your CSS file:

```
.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I do not guarantee as well. What is the point on `relative` positioning here?

Comment: well, i found it on the web. i just randomly put some codes and it worked out! (crazy right?)

Comment: Just because you find something on the web, it doesn't mean it's true in all cases. relative positioning has no effect in this particular case. The issue has occurred because of the invalid statement within the stylesheet as Brian has pointed up.